# В чём разница между LIKE и IN() MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

В чём разница между `LIKE '%...%'` и `IN ()` в MySQL?

Comment: ...а есть сходства? Ну, кроме того, что они оба -- операторы в MySQL.

Comment: @D-side Иногда `IN` можно заменить инвертированным `LIKE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если коротко, то `LIKE` - поиск в строке, `IN` в списке

`LIKE` - выполняет простое сравнение по шаблону. В шаблоне могут быть служебные символы `%` - соответствует любому количеству (в том числе нулевому) символов, `_` - любому одному символу

Например:

```
'Тестовая строка' LIKE '%строка%'
```

даст 1 что означает что левый аргумент подходит под шаблон, указанный в правом аргументе

`IN` проверяет наличие значения (левый аргумент) в списке (правый аргумент)

Например:

```
'один' IN ('один', 'два', 'три')
```

даст 1 что означает что левый аргумент содержится в списке в скобках

Comment: Думаю на такие вопросы нужно отсылать читать справку по SQL

Comment: @nick_n_a К сожалению таких вопросов очень много. И не все умеют читать по-английски. По данному вопросу наверняка можно найти ответ на русском, но свежая документация по MySQL только по-английски. Некоторых это отпугивает (а некоторые просто ленятся :))

Comment: Можно читать справку не обязательно по MySQL.

Comment: Mysql 4 была переведена несколько лет назад, с тех пор вот именно в этом моменте ничего не поменялось (это же ANSI 92 SQL). Но вот желания читать по-английски мало... а лени много.